# Is it safe to delete heapdump.hprof.old?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, filesystem

I'm on a mac book air running OS X 10.9.2. I want to free up space. I see that a file called headdump.hprof.old is occupying a lot of space. Is it safe to delete it? What does it do?[image]

Comment: check your spelling, the screen shot shows heaPdump, not heaDDumpa.

Comment: Heap Dump

A heap dump is a snapshot of the memory of a Java process at a certain point of time. There are different formats for persisting this data, and depending on the format it may contain different pieces of information, but in general the snapshot contains information about the java objects and classes in the heap at the moment the snapshot was triggered. Usually a full GC is triggered before the heap dump is written so it contains information about the remaining object....

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly safe to delete the file.

It is used by programmers in debugging errors in programs. If you're not a developer, not actively debugging that specific program, or not actively involved in a support request regarding a bug in that program - you won't need the file.

Comment: Before recommending the Delete, could you provide reference to some reputable source (nothing personal)

Comment: Well, in this case I'm probably the reputable source. I have used heap dumpers (Java and non-Java) for decades, so I have a pretty good idea what I'm talking about.

Comment: If akh2103 has doubts regarding this, I would just recommend him to move the file away at first and test if the application still works. If it surprisingly turns out that it doesn't work, he can always move the file back again.